# Fabric authentication with kerberos

Tags: python, kerberos, fabric

I'm trying to write a fabric function that puts a script on a remote host and runs it as root. I don't have the root password to login to the machine, nor am I a sudoer, but I do have a root principle in kerberos. Typically, I can connect to a machine as root with the following:

```
kinit username/root
(enter root principle pass)

ssh root@host
```

Connecting in this manner I'm not prompted for a password when ssh'ing to the host.

So I want to emulate this process using fabric. To do so I assumed the following,

> kinit user/root
>
> fab task1 task2 --user=root

Unfortunately fabric prompts me for a password, while I do not have the root password, I can't supply this. Fabric will not let me pass a null for the password as far as I can tell. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Fabric doesn't support Kerberos authentication. If I remember correctly paramiko library doesn't support it either and Fabric uses paramiko (not sure), so it doesn't have corresponding support.

You should go and ask here:
http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/index.html#getting-help

May be use IRC channel so as to get quick response.

Regards,

Comment: In case you are using latest Fabric, it has shifted from paramiko to python ssh library [here (python ssh, project link)](https://github.com/bitprophet/ssh) But sadly that also misses kerberos support.

Comment: right, I found some details in fabric/network.py
it appears this might not be feasible given the limitations of the underlying libraries. Thanks for the info, I will hit up the IRC channel

Answer (score 1):

There is an open pull request for support of Kerberos in Fabric and it looks like it's working and is almost ready to be merged:

https://github.com/fabric/fabric/pull/1261

Answer (score 0):

Fabric 2.6.0 supports gssapi through paramiko (03/2022).  You'll also need to install python-gssapi.

You just need to pass `connect_kwargs` to `__init__()`:

```
class GSSConnection(Connection):
   def __init__(self, host):
      connect_kwargs = dict(
         gss_auth=True,
         gss_deleg_creds=True,
         gss_kex=True,
      )
      super().__init__(host, connect_kwargs=connect_kwargs)
```